# Hibernate - error when running native query

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to use createNativeQuery, but it seems that when I have a joined entity, it is causing a NullPointerException when I call getResultList().

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM table_1 JOIN table_2 ON table_1.id = table_2.table_1_id", Table1.class)
                .getResultList()
```

Comment: Where is the `person_id` that you mention in `@JoinColumn(name = "person_id", ...)` ?

Comment: @f1sh That is the column in the `appointment` table

Comment: what is the result when you run this in a SQL client?

Comment: @ScaryWombat The query itself runs fine when I run it in MySQL; it just returns all of the appointment columns and the person columns

Comment: Check that the `Id` in both fields is actually numeric, not varchar

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the query manually in db and check how many records you can retrieve, *

> **if the query shows 0 records then it is obvious that it will return null to entity manager as a result you are facing this exception**

*. So you can either handle the exception here using try catch block.

I try and get one row and all fields value is null.

Answer (score 0):

You try to write a Typed Query, but * isn't an Apointment but a combination of Appointment and Person.

Try

```
SELECT a.* FROM appointment a JOIN person ON person.id = a.person_id
```

This would limit the Appointments to the Appointments with Persons and return it multiple times, what probably isn't your intention.

Leave out the AppointmentEntiy.class and you get a List of Object[] with the fields of Appointment and Person:

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM appointment JOIN person ON person.id = appointment.person_id")
            .getResultList()
```